# Cosmos python - 429 request rate is large

Tags: python, azure-cosmosdb

I have written a multiprocess python script to bulk load data into my Cosmos database. I decided to use multiprocess to speed up the inserts but I constantly receive the error 429 requests rate is large. More request units may be needed. Is raising the throughput the only way to fix this error?

Comment: hi,any updates here?Does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

According to the key words mentioned in your question,you want to speed up the inserts meanwhile don't want to raise cost as well. I'm afraid it's really challenging.

As we know,[Throughput is provisioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units#request-unit-considerations) for your Azure Cosmos database at all times so that every request to db server consumes resources. This is not related to the number of processes.I know everyone cares about cost,please know about [factors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units#request-unit-considerations) that affect RU charges.

To tuning performance of cosmos db,you could refer to this [performance tips document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips).Or you could consider [synthetic partition key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/synthetic-partition-keys#use-a-partition-key-with-a-random-suffix) for your documents which could improve the write performance.